# Find which GPU a GpuMat is on

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

With multiple GPUs on my system, I would like to find an easy way to determine which GPU a `cv::cuda::GpuMat` is allocated on. For example, ignoring errors:

```
int numDevices = cv::cuda::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount();
// Choose a random GPU
cudaSetDevice(rand()%numDevices);
cv::cuda::GpuMat foo(5, 5, CV_8UC1);
// Choose another random GPU
cudaSetDevice(rand()%numDevices);
```

Now, which GPU does `foo` live on? I'm using OpenCV 3 and CUDA 8, in case there is a version-specific solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea how or whether this works in OpenCV, but it is possible to query a pointer via the CUDA runtime  API and see whether it is a host or device pointer and which device it is associated with on platforms with unified addressing support.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED), you can query the pointer of the device memory backing an allocation with `cudaPointerGetAttributes` and it will report the device number. If you are working on a platform without unified addressing support this will not work, and a runtime error will be reported if you try.

Working from the example in the question, `foo` may be queried as follows:

```
cudaPointerAttributes attrs;
cudaPointerGetAttributes(&attrs, foo.data);
std::cout << "GpuMat foo resides on GPU #" << attrs.device << '\n';
```

Comment: @KenY-N: that is fine. I might want error checking for the case where the platform doesn't support UVA, but that is an implementation detail